# MKPolylineView not rendered on MKMapView till MKMapView is clicked

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have a view controller, where I initialize a mkmapview programatically, and set the view controller to be the delegate of mkmapview. Also, this mapview is added as a subview to scrollview in the view controller class.

I add a mkpolyline to mkmapview, and I have

```
 - (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
```

However, viewforoverlay is not called when view controller is loaded, but it is called when I click/touch mapview and drag/move it around

Answer (score 0):

This problem is typically seen if you add the `MKOverlay` to the `MKMapView` *prior* to assigning the delegate. When you add the `MKOverlay` to the `MKMapView`, the delegate method `mapView:viewForOverlay:` is called. If you have not assigned the delegate *by that time*, you will not see the overlay renderer in the initial render.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this line after you add your MKPolylineView overlay:

```
[myMapView setNeedsRedisplay];
```

This is how I add a route to my map:

```
-(void)drawRoute
{
    ...

    routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointArr count:totalPoints];

    [geoMap addOverlay:routeLine];

    ....
}

-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{    
    MKPolylineView *lineView = [[[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay] autorelease];

    UIColor *lineColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0];

    lineView.fillColor = lineColor;
    lineView.strokeColor = lineColor;

    [lineColor release];

    lineView.lineWidth = 12;   
    lineView.alpha = 1;
    return lineView;
}
```

Comment: but method  `- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay` is not even called, and I never add overlayview to mapview object. Overlayview is determined when mapview makes a call to above method on its delegate

Comment: btw, this mapview is added as a subview to uiscrollview. Not sure if it matters

Comment: Can you show your code for adding MKPolylineView overlay? I don't know how you're doing it but see my editing answer on how I add MKPolylineView as overlay to my map.

Comment: `[self.scroller addSubview:mapView];`

    [mapView addOverlay:routeLine];
    [mapView setVisibleMapRect:_routeRect];

//    mapView.scrollEnabled = NO;
//    mapView.zoomEnabled = NO;
    
    //set this class as delegate for this class
    [mapView setDelegate:self];



- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay


I have similar code like yours, except my mapview is added to scrollview, and polylineview gets rendered only when I touch/move the mkmapview.

So everything seems to work fine only *after* I move the mapview

Comment: Actually I figured out that, commenting the below line makes it work

//[mapView setVisibleMapRect:_routeRect];

Is there a way to use setVisibleMapRect and make viewforoverlay work